# readLine skips lines when outfiling

Tags: java, bufferedreader

This piece of code does not seemt o work; I have 10 lines in the csv file but only 5 are being printed out.. only lines 2,4,6,8,10 are being printed out.

```
String text = CSVFile.readLine();
    while (text != null){
    //lines.add(infile.next());
    //outfile.println(lines);
    outfile.println(CSVFile.readLine());

    if (CSVFile.readLine()==null)
        break;
    }
```

I think I have an idea why it is skipping the odd numbers, But i do not know how to fix it.
since I am telling it to readLine() twice, I believe it sips from the 1st one and then the 3rd and then so on.

Comment: You should give us the implementation of CSVFile.

Comment: Fix it by calling rwadLine() only once and storing the result in a variable; then you can use it twice or 100 times, as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you call `readLine` twice within the while loop.  Try this:

```
String text = CSVFile.readLine();
    while (text != null){
    outfile.println(text);
    text = CSVFile.readLine();

    if (text==null)
        break;
```

The reader is stateful and **remembers** where it read from last time you called the method...

Comment: Still prints out only the even numebrs

Comment: Try again - I made a minor modification to print to the file prior to reading from within the loop

Comment: The change worked.. Thank you.. what i was missing out was that where ever that term occurred (CSVFile.readLine()), it would count.. this  means that even when checking the if statement it would increment by one..

Answer (score 1):

Every call to [the `readLine()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) consumes the next line of input.  You are calling it twice each `while` loop iteration.

Try modifying your loop so that it calls `readLine()` only once per loop.  The standard way is:

```
String text;
while ((text = CSVFile.readLine()) != null)
{
    // Process the line here.
}
```

This assigns the line to `text` and compares it to `null` all in one line.

Comment: Then somehow you're still calling `readLine()` twice per loop.

Answer (score 1):

Simple.  Don't call readLine twice.

```
String text = CSVFile.readLine();
while (text != null){
    outfile.println(text);

    text = CSVFile.readLine();
}
```

Comment: If I dont call it twice.. it will remain on the first line in the initial call.. which repeats the first line 10 times

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is correct. In fact, the `if` block is completely obsolete as you have that check in your `while` loop condition.  Try  this instead:

```
String text = CSVFile.readLine();
while (text != null) {
    System.out.println(text);
    text = CSVFile.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are skipping lines because you are reading twice.

```
String text = CSVFile.readLine(); <-- here
while (text != null){
    outfile.println(CSVFile.readLine()); <-- here

    if (CSVFile.readLine()==null) 
        break;
}
```

Just read from it once.

```
String text = CSVFile.readLine();
while (text != null){
    outfile.println(text);
    text = CSVFile.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because when you call `readLine()`, it advances the position of the cursor by one.

```
String text = CSVFile.readLine(); <- line 1
while (text != null){
    outfile.println(CSVFile.readLine()); <- print line 2 
    if (CSVFile.readLine()==null) <- goes to line 3 so next time the println will print line 4 
       break;
}
```

To avoid that do :

```
String text = null;
while ((text = CSV.readLine()) != null){
  outfile.println(text); 
}
```

Comment: Prints out only the odd lines

Answer (score 0):

In your code what happens is, you call readLine() methods twice before print. Try following,

```
String text = CSVFile.readLine();
while (text != null){
  outfile.println(text);
  text = CSVFile.readLine();
}
```